# Jackson optional field empty() vs null

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to use Optional in a POJO to indicate when a json field can be null, absent, or present. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to configure jackson to not treat `Optional.empty()` and `null` as the same. For `empty()`, I want the field to be ignored. None of the JsonInclude values seem to do this. `Jdk8Module#configureAbsentsAsNulls()` looked promising, but it doesn't change the results of my tests. Is there a way to do this?

**tl;dr**
`null` values *should* be serialized, `Optional.empty()` should not be serialized.

Here are some tests exhibiting the behavior I'm trying to achieve.

```
class POJO {
    public Optional<String> content;
}

private ObjectMapper getMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
}

@org.junit.Test
public void testAbsent() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getMapper();

    POJO pojo = new POJO();
    pojo.content = Optional.empty();

    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);

    assertEquals("{}", result);
}

@org.junit.Test
public void testNull() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getMapper();

    POJO pojo = new POJO();
    pojo.content = null;

    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);

    assertEquals("{\"content\":null}", result);
}

@org.junit.Test
public void testPresent() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getMapper();

    POJO pojo = new POJO();
    pojo.content = Optional.of("Hello");

    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);

    assertEquals("{\"content\":\"Hello\"}", result);
}
```

Comment: Would you please post a minimal example test case that you expect to pass but fails (e.g., configure the mapper, set a field to empty, serialize, show the output)?

Comment: Just added some tests. Sorry they weren't there to begin with.

Comment: As I said in the original question (and as indicated in the tests), null should be serialized and empty() shouldn't. This isn't the default behavior of the module. That question doesn't answer how to achieve this behavior.

Comment: @Panda were you able to figure this out ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement using `JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM` rule and custom `value` filter:

```java
class OptionalFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Optional && ((Optional<?>) obj).isEmpty();
    }
}

class POJO {
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = OptionalFilter.class)
    public Optional<String> content;
}
```

with setting `configureAbsentsAsNulls` to `true`:

```java
new Jdk8Module().configureAbsentsAsNulls(true)
```